# How do I copy root folder and contents if content in file is true?

Tags: powershell, xml-parsing

To give some context, I have two root folders, one `source` and one `destination`. I am trying to write a PowerShell script that goes through a specific file in each folder and if that file meets the criteria, the entire folder of that file gets copied over.

Currently, I am only able to copy the contents of the folder and not the entire folder itself.

I found that using `(Get-Item $files).Directory` gets me the path of the file it's checking. However, when I use `Get-Item -Path $fileRoot -Recurse` it comes back saying that `-Recurse` is unknown.

Below is the full script.

```cs
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\testPath\source\*\content*.xml" 

$files | ForEach-Object {
    $file = [xml](Get-Content $_.FullName);

    $nodeXML = $file.SelectNodes("//*[local-name()='testPathq']"); 

    if ($file.ParentNode.InnerXml.Contains('testPathq') -eq $nodeXML) {
        $fileRoot = (Get-Item $files).Directory
        $destination = 'C:\testPath\destination\'

        Get-ChildItem -Path $fileRoot -Recurse |
            Copy-Item -Destination $destination -Force
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this file exist in multiple sub directories? i.e. can a folder be flagged more than one for a copy? `Get-Item` does not have recurse. `Get-ChildItem` does

Comment: `Get-ChildItem -Path $fileRoot -Recurse | Copy-Item -Destination $destination -Force` -> `Get-ChildItem -Path $fileRoot | Copy-Item -Destination $destination -Recurse -Force`?

Comment: @Matt Yes and no. Each content in the file is unique except for the fact that some have a node called `testPathq`. I'm looking for all files with that node so I can copy the parent folder to the Destination.

@AnsgarWiechers Moving `-Recurse` to the end of `Copy-Item` does the same thing, which just copies over the content of the folder, instead of the entire folder and its contents.

Comment: Thanks you, two! I found my answer. Per @Matt's comment I changed `Get-ChildItem` to `Get-Item` and moved `-Recurse` to the position where @AnsgarWiecher suggested.